# create columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Good night! I'm brazilian and I don't speak english very well. I work a database with more than 10000 rows, represented by the example below.

```
df <- data.frame(
  PROCESS = c(180022121, 180022121, 180022105, 180022105, 180022097, 180022097, 180022097, 180022501, 180022501), 
  NAME = c("A_NONIMATO", "A_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO"),DATE = c("02/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "02/01/2018", "02/01/2018"), 
  CRIME = c("ART.33", "ART.33", "ART.35", "ART.33", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.155", "ART.157", "ART.14CP"))
```

My question: I want to create columns (CRIME2, CRIME3, CRIME4 and etc.) separating crimes in lines observing the same process, same name and same date. As many columns as there are crimes.

To look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(PROCESS = c(180022121, 180022105, 180022097, 180022501), 
                  NAME = c("A_NONIMATO", "C_NONIMATO", "D_NONIMATO", "G_NONIMATO"), 
                  DATE = c("02/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "02/01/2018"), 
                  CRIME = c("ART.33", "ART.35", "ART.155", "ART.157"),  
                  CRIME2 = c("ART.33", "ART.33", "ART.155", "ART.14CP"), 
                  CRIME3 = c("NA", "NA", "ART.155", "NA"), 
                  CRIME4 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"))
```

Comment: don't have time to answer, but you want `tidyr::spread`: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html

Comment: Or `pivot_wider` for more functionality.

Answer (score 3):

We can create a unique identifier column based on `PROCESS` `NAME` and `DATE` and reshape the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(PROCESS, NAME, DATE) %>%
  mutate(temp = paste0("CRIME", row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = temp, values_from = CRIME)

#    PROCESS NAME       DATE       CRIME1  CRIME2   CRIME3 
#      <dbl> <fct>      <fct>      <fct>   <fct>    <fct>  
#1 180022121 A_NONIMATO 02/01/2018 ART.33  ART.33   NA     
#2 180022105 C_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.35  ART.33   NA     
#3 180022097 D_NONIMATO 01/01/2018 ART.155 ART.155  ART.155
#4 180022501 G_NONIMATO 02/01/2018 ART.157 ART.14CP NA
```